How connect V2ray server in python?
I'm programming a python telegram bot. I need use a proxy that changes host IP to other location. Because telegram has been filtered in my country.
It's worked in my system truly when I connect to VPN, but I don't know how use VPN or V2ray config in code form. I bought host and V2ray config and just need a Sample Code that works with VMESS Config.

use v2ray to start a socks proxy and then connect that socks proxy server with your code.
How to make python Requests work via SOCKS proxy

I can connect to SOCKS proxy... I have its code. But I have a good VMESS proxy for my needed IP location that I paid for it. I can connect to that with V2Ray app. But I don't know how must connect to it in python with codes.

I said... I just need a Sample Code that works with VMESS Config in python codes.
